# jmeter Regular expression get url link

Tags: jmeter, expression

I get the response message from jmeter5.3.

```
{"header":{"sndDt":"2021-02-01 20:13:37","msgCd":"CPAS.911.110.01","trxTp":"file.trans","trxChnlTp":"08","srvProNo":"870058120000000161","mrchntNo":"870058120000000161","corrId":"7b8b0f5623e14e3f83bbd68b56d14262","oriCorrId":"CPAS0000000000000000000000013094","signMethod":"RSA","signNo":"CN=063@202010150917224561@merAliaEN@85810850/OU=Enterprises/OU=ncc/O=ncc@operation@ca/C=cn","reserved":"????"},"body":{"status":{"sysRtnCd":"00000000","sysRtnDesc":"系统处理成功","sysDtTm":"2021-02-01 20:13:37","bizRtnCd":"00000000","bizRtnDesc":"业务处理成功","bizDtTm":"2021-02-01 20:13:37"},"srvProNo":"870058120000000161","fileTransURL":"http://36.110.9.124:9066/godfs/group1/upload","scene":"cpas","verifCd":"098272"}}&sign=W8T4Aucq96Oi2K7v2o8e7VQJwdPriyLDd1CcmJnjP3P1n5A4KMDsQ54kfpmz8uahn9ROl85lbGxQ0g6aG4HgI+EQ7k3AOVTvf385KN/ycz5cB/+g82v6W8ES/1Kvbcvr4gCe+NhpUUoAYNuBoprxcz1xb3JU12GlHY6OFLxLDFJ5hLkSnu+7B4SDQqU9UyZR7dJGHPz1pnF4UQrfAP9FjdVlG4boOTdHZznNqm+sBFgRTEZLQuztde6mgOhqMmteL1oEBKRS2YKufpbv5TeK9Xuog4eoH4zP2It05Rg6UHEN366dzUryu/Kl7FBchiTl11O5Cxrm6FLlTI5+SCqcHg==
```

I use jmeter Regular expression get "fileTransURL":"http://36.110.9.124:9066/godfs/group1/upload". I wang to get this url: http://36.110.9.124:9066/godfs/group1/upload.I set Jmeter Regular expression: "fileTransURL":"(.+*)".

But not get this url.only get "%7Burl%7D" .Please help check. Thanks!

[enter image description here][1]
[enter image description here][2]

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want regular expression it's a better idea to allow arbitrary amount of optional whitespaces like:

```
"fileTransURL"\s*:\s*"(.+?)"
```

[image]

See [Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) JMeter User Manual chapter for more details.

However your response seems to be [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) so it makes sense to consider going for [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide) like:

```
body.fileTransURL
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple option is to use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)

JSON Path Expressions: `$..fileTransURL` (means find second level parameter fileTransURL)

Match No. `1` ( find first match)